Why won't hb-shape read files when passed a variable?
I have a script that where I'm trying to check to see if a given font has a given character in it. hb-shape (from harfbuzz) is able to do this in the shell:
$ hb-shape "/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Courier New.ttf" t
[t=0+1229]

But when I to do it in the script I get:
hb-shape: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Courier New.ttf : Failed reading file
Try `hb-shape --help' for more information.

Here is my script:
#!/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.26/bin/bash
mapfile -t fonts < <(fc-list : file | head -4 | tr -d ':' | awk '{$1=$1};1')

for font in "${fonts[@]}"; do
    hb-shape "$font" t
done

Why won't hb-shape handle the variable as an input?
I have tried:

hb-shape "$font" t
hb-shape "${font}" t
hb-shape '"'$font'"' t

Thank you!
Details
System: Mac OS 14.1.2
ZSH (my terminal): zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0)
Bash (my script): 5.2.26
fc-list (part of fontconfig package): fontconfig version 2.15.0
hb-shape (HarfBuzz) 8.4.0
Details re: fc-list
$ fc-list | head -4
fc-list | head -4
/System/Library/Fonts/SFCompact.ttf: .SF Compact:style=Thin
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttc: .Apple Color Emoji UI:style=Regular
/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Verdana Bold.ttf: Verdana:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,Lodia
/System/Library/Fonts/SFNSMonoItalic.ttf: .SF NS Mono:style=Medium Italic

$ fc-list : file | head -4
fc-list : file | head -4
/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Courier New.ttf:
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Braille Pinpoint 6 Dot.ttf:
/System/Library/Fonts/KohinoorTelugu.ttc:
/System/Library/Fonts/ヒラギノ角ゴシック W2.ttc:

$ fc-list : file | head -4 | tr -d ':' | awk '{$1=$1};1'
fc-list : file | head -4 | tr -d ':' | awk '{$1=$1};1'
/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Courier New.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Braille Pinpoint 6 Dot.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/KohinoorTelugu.ttc
/System/Library/Fonts/ヒラギノ角ゴシック W2.ttc

My attempt with the last two commands (tr, awk) is to clean up the :  that is left on the file names.
hexdump
I added hexdump to the main loop:
for font in "${fonts[@]}"; do
    echo "'$font'";
    hexdump -C <<<"$font"
done

$ ./finding-char.sh
./finding-char.sh
'/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Courier New.ttf'
00000000  2f 53 79 73 74 65 6d 2f  4c 69 62 72 61 72 79 2f  |/System/Library/|
00000010  46 6f 6e 74 73 2f 53 75  70 70 6c 65 6d 65 6e 74  |Fonts/Supplement|
00000020  61 6c 2f 43 6f 75 72 69  65 72 20 4e 65 77 2e 74  |al/Courier New.t|
00000030  74 66 0a                                          |tf.|
00000033
'/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Braille Pinpoint 6 Dot.ttf'
00000000  2f 53 79 73 74 65 6d 2f  4c 69 62 72 61 72 79 2f  |/System/Library/|
00000010  46 6f 6e 74 73 2f 41 70  70 6c 65 20 42 72 61 69  |Fonts/Apple Brai|
00000020  6c 6c 65 20 50 69 6e 70  6f 69 6e 74 20 36 20 44  |lle Pinpoint 6 D|
00000030  6f 74 2e 74 74 66 0a                              |ot.ttf.|
00000037
'/System/Library/Fonts/KohinoorTelugu.ttc'
00000000  2f 53 79 73 74 65 6d 2f  4c 69 62 72 61 72 79 2f  |/System/Library/|
00000010  46 6f 6e 74 73 2f 4b 6f  68 69 6e 6f 6f 72 54 65  |Fonts/KohinoorTe|
00000020  6c 75 67 75 2e 74 74 63  0a                       |lugu.ttc.|
00000029
'/System/Library/Fonts/ヒラギノ角ゴシック W2.ttc'
00000000  2f 53 79 73 74 65 6d 2f  4c 69 62 72 61 72 79 2f  |/System/Library/|
00000010  46 6f 6e 74 73 2f e3 83  92 e3 83 a9 e3 82 ad e3  |Fonts/..........|
00000020  82 99 e3 83 8e e8 a7 92  e3 82 b3 e3 82 99 e3 82  |................|
00000030  b7 e3 83 83 e3 82 af 20  57 32 2e 74 74 63 0a     |....... W2.ttc.|
0000003f

So it appears there is a new line: 0a. I'm struggling to figure out how to remove that.
Based on this answer I tried the following, but it returned the same output.
hexdump -C <<<"${font//[$'\t\r\n']}"

I also get the same output when I try with:
for font in "${fonts[@]%:*}"; do
    echo "'$font'";
    hexdump -C <<<"$font"
done

Solution
With the help from @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub the following works:
mapfile -t fonts < <(fc-list : file | tr -d ':' | awk '{$1=$1};1')

for font in "${fonts[@]}"; do
    printf "'$font'";
    hb-shape "$(printf '%s' "$font")" ⌘
done | grep -v '\.notdef\|gid0\|\.null'


I don't know the fc-list command (it's not found in my Mac .... perhaps you have installed it), so I don't know the output format it produces; but for debugging, I would print the content of the font variable with hexdump -C <<<$font.

Adjustment to @user1934428's recommendation: use hexdump -C <<<"$font" since there's a bug in old versions of bash if variables in a here-string aren't double-quoted... and macOS ships with an old version of bash.

FYI hb-shape "$font" t is the correct syntax. hb-shape "${font}" t would also work but the { and } are doing nothing. hb-shape '"'$font'"' t is wrong - that's enclosing the double quotes within single quotes and so making them literal rather than using the double quotes to protect $font from the shell and then leaving  the $font variable exposed to the shell for word splitting, etc.

| tr -d ':' | awk '{$1=$1};1' would fail for any file name that contains :s or spaces so don't do that. Run fc-list : file | cat -A or similar so we can see white space in the fc-list : file output and then [edit] your question to show what that output looks like so we can help you.

You could do: mapfile -t fonts < <(fc-list : file|head -n4);for font in "${fonts[@]%:*}";do hb-shape "$font" t;done this will only drop trailing :*.

Reading ...ew.ttf : Failed... notice the space between ttf and :!  This mean the space wasn't correctly dropped by awk!  As @EdMorton said: don't do that! Btw this awk syntax will replace multiple space by only one space and so on (if they work)...

The newline is added by <<<"$font" bash syntax! You could avoid this by using < <(printf '%s' "$font")  instead. I will more suspect your japan filename to be problematic...

@user1934428 - fc-list is part of fontconfig. Thanks for the hexdump rec.

@GordonDavisson - thanks for the tip. FWIIW I'm using the newer bash.

@EdMorton - thanks for giving my confidence in that direction. I didn't see any file names with : so I wasn't worried about that. cat -A failed.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub - I tried %:* and it didn't work either. When I run it without the awk I am seeing the space show up in the hexdump so I'm pretty sure it is working. But you got it with that last one! hb-shape "$(printf '%s' "$font")" t works!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The 0a you see is an artefact produced by hexdump, as you can verify with X=X; hexdump -C <<<$X. This is nothing you need to worry. By and large, the path inside your font variable looks good. I would verify whether that file really exists, and what permissions it has (for instance by doing ls -l $font. If the file does not exist, the problem is most likely in fc-list.

@RyanJM I said "cat -A or similar so we can see white space in the fc-list : file output"(emphasis added here). If the version of cat on your system doesn't have -A then try cat -te or od -c or something else to make the spaces show up.

Based on what you've now posted, this isn't your current problem but if your file names contained any :s or white space other than single blank chars then | tr -d ':' would remove the :s and then awk '{$1=$1};1'would change all that white space to individual blanks thereby changing/corrupting your file name so definitely don't do either of those."$(printf '%s' "$font")"is identical to just"$font". Don't do printf "'$font'"as it'll fail when$fontcontains any printf formatting char line%s, always do printf '%s' "$font"` instead IF you need that (which you don't).

grep -v '\.notdef\|gid0\|\.null' will fail if your file name contains any of those strings so don't do that. Not sure what you're trying to do with that or your printfs.

Why did the t at the end of hb-shape "$font" t in your original script at the start of your question become ⌘ in the script you say is working at the end of your question?

Based on the output of fc-list : file | head -4 you show, replacing | tr -d ':' | awk '{$1=$1};1' with sed 's/:$//' would make your script more robust and efficient but there's no indication in your question of any problem with your files names and no problem with your original shell script that'd cause it to fail using those file names.  My best guess at this point is that the script in your question is not the script you're actually running that's producing the error message in your question. Add set -x to the top of your script, run it again, then post THAT output.

The 0xa you see at the end of the hexdump -C <<<"$font" output isn't because there's a newline in $font, it's because the <<<  construct adds a newline after $font to ensure that the result of that construct is a valid POSIX text line/file but hexdump isn't a text-processing tool (unlike sed, grep, awk, etc.) and so doesn't require input that ends in a newline so - don't do that. Do hexdump -C < <(printf '%s' "$font") instead to have hexdump -C run on the contents of $font as-is.

Also try adding export LC_ALL=C at the top of your script to see if your problem is related to your locale.
